# MPAndroidChart Line chart scrollview overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, mpandroidchart

I am facing a problem when adding a scrollview to my layout. When ever I change the orientation to landscape and scroll, the views seem to overlap [image: Portrait view][image: Landscape view]

Following below is the code from the layout file. Can any one help me to figure out why the Details and the chart over lap???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/line_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>


        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:columnCount="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:text="@string/detail_symbol"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/symbolValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="IBM" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:text="@string/price"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/priceValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="Price" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/percentage_change"
                android:text="@string/percentage_change"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="Percentage change" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/percentageChangeValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text=".09%" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/absolute_change"
                android:text="@string/absolute_change"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/absolutechangeValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="5.5" />

       </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use external scroll views

Comment 'computeScroll()' method or  'Utils.postInvalidateOnAnimation(mChart);'
in the bellow path. This method may block your thread for 2, 3 minutes and this leads to delay, lagging, live value update issues , etc..

com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/BarLineChartTouchListener.java

Definitely this will resolve all scrolling issues like delay, hangs etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/line_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>


        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:columnCount="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:text="@string/detail_symbol"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/symbolValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="IBM" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:text="@string/price"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/priceValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="Price" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/percentage_change"
                android:text="@string/percentage_change"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="Percentage change" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/percentageChangeValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text=".09%" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/absolute_change"
                android:text="@string/absolute_change"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/absolutechangeValue"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                tools:text="5.5" />

       </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. I don't see much difference in the code too

Comment: In LinearLayout check : android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"